# Nesper example add assembly reference - namespace com / Support / UpdateEventArgs /

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, nesper

I'm trying to understand how NEsper works and see the example codes like Feed, ATM, AutoId, Transaction and so on. when I try to build the solution, I get many errors. the type or namespace com / Support / UpdateEventArgs / ... could not be found. Assembly reference should be added. Can anyone tell me where to find those namespaces and how to add those references?
thanks in advance!
Narsu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The Nuget packages are [common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEsper.Common/8.0.0-beta-1), [compiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEsper.Compiler/8.0.0-beta-1) and [runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEsper.Runtime/8.0.0-beta-1). You can see the package references there.